# How do I open a file from another git branch?

Tags: git

I'd like to open a file from another branch in the current git repository. I have seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7856416/2072269), but the suggestions for combining it with Vim are cumbersome (pipe to Vim, open stdin, set filetype, etc. manually). Is there a simpler way that retains syntax highlighting, filetype settings, etc.?

If it helps:

- I have the [fugitive](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive) plugin installed (though rarely used).
- I don't need to modify the file

The file can be the file for the currently open buffer, or a different one.

Comment: @Andy this question isn't *about* fugitive per se. I happened to have it installed already, but I'd have been just as happy with methods that used some alternative plugin, or no plugin at all.

Comment: And the accepted answer is about fugitive, which is why I tagged it.

Comment: @AndyLester and if somebody posts a simple enough way that doesn't need fugitive, or if a better plugin than fugitive comes along and that's used in an answer, I could very well accept those instead.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You can use `:Gedit`/`:Gsplit`/`:Gvsplit`/... with the form `{revision}:{filename}`

```
:Gedit branch:/foo/bar.c
```

Note: If the file is the same as the current file you can abbreviate the command like so: `:Gsplit branch:%`.

It is often the case that a diff of the current file is preferred than just opening the file on a different branch. You can do this via `:Gdiff {branch}`.

For more help see:

```
:h fugitive-:Gedit
:h fugitive-revision
:h fugitive-:Gdiff
:h c_%
```

You may also want to check out [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes in the [Fugitive Series](http://vimcasts.org/blog/2011/05/the-fugitive-series/).

Comment: Beautiful! Curious: what happens if I modify a file so opened?

Comment: @muru You will notice that the buffer is opened up in a read only buffer (probably notice an `[RO]` in the status line).

Comment: yep, it's there.

Comment: `fugitive` needs the path from the root of the repository.  The answer already cover this, but I wrongly assumed that fugitive could understand when we are in a particular subdirectory of the repo.

Comment: amazing.. first time using fugitive.. even though I had it installed for a long time :)

Comment: @PeterRincker, What I found though is that if I have a file open from one commit, I can't jut do a `:tabe` and open a file from another commit. Is that the designed behavior of `fugitive`?

Comment: You can open `:Gedit` to open all manner of git objects. I think it would be best to give better examples of what you try to do. Make sure you are using the revision format `{commit-or-branch}:{file-path}`. I would highly recommend reading fugitive’s help page and watching the vimcasts episodes

Comment: To reflect to @muru's [question above](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/3746/how-do-i-open-a-file-from-another-git-branch#comments-3748), I needed to compare the same file on different branches, and **edit** it on one of the branches. When `:Gdiff my-branch` is issued, `my-branch`'s version will be opened in the left pane in read-only mode, but the right side is fully editable.

Answer (score 20):

This is a little more broad than what OP asked, but for people not wanting to use plugins, and possibly other revision control systems, this little snippet tends to work fairly well:

```
:new
:r! git show branch:file
:1d
```

It creates a new window and shows the file there by reading the output of the given command into the new buffer. This of course works with any external command, not just git.

Example for bzr (where REV syntax can specify a branch):

```
:new
:r! bzr cat -r REV file
:1d
```

Example for hg (not sure about branches in hg; don't use it enough)

```
:new
:r! hg cat -r REV file
:1d
```

Example for svn (

```
:new
:r! svn cat file@REV
:1d
```

You would still probably want to set the filetype to get syntax highlighting like in the SO posts, but at least you don't have to mess with piping.

Once opened you can save it under a new name with `:w filename` or `:saveas filename`, since Vim won't have a filename for it yet. If you don't want to be able to edit it, you can also throw in a `:setlocal readonly` and/or `:setlocal nomodifiable`.

### -Edit: Automatic Filetype-

It's a little more work, but you can ask Vim to guess the filetype with

```
:filetype detect
```

But, since Vim doesn't have a name yet, this doesn't always work well (for example, I pulled in some C code and it guessed `filtype=conf`.

We can give it a name by saving it, but we don't want to overwrite a possibly existing file. We can also just set the filename (Thanks @PeterRincker!), but again, we don't want to risk collisions. Since it is unlikely that a file exists that is both the branchname and filename together, we'll concatenate them with some arbitrary separator

```
:exe "silent file " . "branch" . "-" . "file"
:filetype detect
```

Where `"file"` is replaced with the actual filename and `"branch"` with the branch name

Of course, at this point we are almost writing a plugin ;-)

Thowing it all together, here it is as a git specific function you could drop in your vimrc:

```
function! GitFile(branch,file)
    new
    exe "silent r! git show " . a:branch . ":" . a:file
    1d
    exe "silent file " . a:branch . "-" . a:file
    filetype detect
    setlocal readonly     "don't allow saving
    setlocal nomodified   "allow easy quitting without saving
    setlocal nomodifiable "don't allow modification
endfunction
```

which you could wrap in a command or call directly e.g. `call GitFile("whateverBranch","myfile.c")`. You'll get a new window with a buffer named `whateverBranch-myfile.c`

Comment: And can I get it to detect filetype, syntax, etc. automatically with this method?

Comment: Sadly not without some more work; I updated the post

Comment: I do recommend using the plugin method from @PeterRinker's post if you can. It should do a lot of the nice things you'd like. I mostly wanted to show that one needn't leave the editor nor deal with the hassles of piping to get the data, and I know that there are some people who hate having to use plugins.

Comment: I just added a bit to be able to detect filetype. It is no longer something you'd want to just type on-the-fly, but could work as an easy addition to a .vimrc. Using a specific plugin will still probably work better.

Comment: You might want to look into using `:file` to name your file instead of having a temporary file. See `:h :file`

Comment: @PeterRincker excellent suggestion! I'll try it and update in a bit. I had actually checked `:help :file` when I was writing the post, but my version of Vim (7.4 on Ubunut 14.04) only says `:file` prints the filename and additional info (like ctrl-g), not mentionaing anything about it changing the filename if given an argument. Just now found that tidbit under `:help :file_f`  :-)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using simple `git difftool`, as there is no plugin required and syntax highlighting is retained.

```
git difftool branch -- path/to/file
```

Or from any other commit:

```
git difftool commit -- path/to/file
```

Comment: Quick and easy option (might need vimdiff as difftool in git config)